# How is a function able to know the exact return value depending on whether the parameter is undefined or not?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Activity {
    eat: () => void
}

interface Person {
    activity?: Activity
}

const activity = <T extends Person>(person: T) => ({
    eat: person.activity && person.activity.eat
})

const tom = {
    activity: {
        eat: () => {}
    }
}

const tomAct = activity(tom)
tomAct.eat() // should know `eat` does exist

const bobAct = activity({})
bobAct.eat // should know `eat` is undefined
```

You can see tomAct.eat will return `eat: (() => void) | undefined` but `tomAct` in this case knowns that `eat: (() => void` and bobAct is known `undefined`.

Does Typescript support this case? How can I solve that?

===

"typescript": "^3.1.2",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that control flow analysis doesn't really work very well on generics.  The compiler is essentially widening `T` to `Person` for the purposes of control flow analysis (figuring out what type `person.activity && person.activity.eat` will be), so the inferred return type of `activity()` is the same as that of the concrete (non-generic) version of the function:

```
const activityConcrete = (person: Person) => ({
  eat: person.activity && person.activity.eat
}); // {eat: ()=>void | undefined}
```

In order to get the behavior you want you either need to walk the compiler through the analysis (which is sometimes impossible) or just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) the return type you expect.  Traditionally what you'd do here is to use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to represent the relationship between input and output types:

```
function activity(person: { activity: Activity }): Activity;
function activity(person: { activity?: undefined }): { eat: undefined };
function activity(person: Person): { eat: Activity['eat'] | undefined };
function activity(person: Person): { eat: Activity['eat'] | undefined } {
  return {
    eat: person.activity && person.activity.eat
  }
}
```

As of TypeScript 2.8 you can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to represent the same thing:

```
type PersonEat<T extends Person> = T['activity'] extends infer A ? 
  A extends Activity ? A['eat'] : undefined : never;

const activity = <T extends Person>(person: T) => ({
  eat: person.activity && person.activity.eat
} as { eat: PersonEat<T> })
```

Either way should result in similar behavior:

```
const tom = {
  activity: {
    eat: () => {}
  }
}
const bob = {};

const tomAct = activity(tom)
tomAct.eat() // okay 

const bobAct = activity(bob)
bobAct.eat // undefined
```

So that works.

---

Please note that there's a bit of a wrinkle with how it treats a `Person` without an `activity`.  The type of `bob` above is `{}`, which is treated as a [top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type) for objects, meaning that it [absorbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law) any other object type you union with it.  That is, in:

```
const tomOrBob = Math.random() < 0.5 ? tom : bob; // type is {}
```

it is inferred that `tomOrBob` is of type `{} | {activity: Activity}`, which is collapsed to just `{}`.  So the compiler forgets that `tomOrBob` might have an `activity`.  And that leads to the following incorrect behavior:

```
const tomOrBobActivity = activity(tomOrBob);
tomOrBobActivity.eat; // undefined  but it should be (()=>void) | undefined
```

If you're okay with that overzealous undefinedness, fine.  Otherwise, you need to explicitly tell the compiler to remember that `activity` is missing from `bob`:

```
const bob: { activity?: undefined } = {}; // bob definitely is missing activity

const bobAct = activity(bob);
bobAct.eat // still undefined as desired 

const tomOrBob = Math.random() < 0.5 ? tom : bob;

const tomOrBobAct = activity(tomOrBob);
tomOrBobAct.eat; // (() => void) | undefined
```

And that behaves as desired.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative answer @jcal.

Comment: One more question about definition `PersonEat` why you use `never` in the end, I though it will be undefined. Could you tell me what i'm wrong?

Comment: The construction `X extends infer Y ? Z : never` uses [conditional type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to assign `X` to a new type variable `Y`.  The conditional type `X extends infer Y` will always be satisfied, so the `never` is ignored.  In the case of `PersonEat`, I wanted to make `T['activity']` [distribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) across a union, but you need a "naked" type parameter like `A`, so I reassigned it.

Comment: If it's too confusing, I'd recommend staying with the overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is a transpiler that works on **compile time**, therefore it can know only the things that are known at that time.

You requirement is **runtime** requirement, the value of some property will be known only at runtime, therefore it is not possible to do with TS.